# Use environment variable to mount a directory in docker-compose - not mounting?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables

I cannot seem to mount the appropriate directory in my docker container through the `docker-compose.yml` file.

My docker-compose looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  apache:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/apache/apache.Dockerfile
    profiles: [ "apache" ]
    volumes:
      - ${APP_DIRECTORY}:/app/my_app
    env_file:
      # This contains variables needed inside the container
      - .env 
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

From all [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/) and all the other things I've found while googling online - it would appear that as long as `APP_DIRECTORY` exists as an environment variable in the shell where I am running `docker compose up -d --build apache` it should work as expected and mount the appropriate directory in the container.

If I run `echo ${APP_DIRECTORY}` in the same shell, I see the appropriate path: `/Users/myuser/myrepos/my_app`

My .Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM httpd:2.4.57

# set environment variables
# prevents Python from writing pyc files to disc
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
# prevents Python from buffering stdout and stderr
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Update the system
RUN apt update

# additional setup here (installing some libraries)

# I should see the appropriate data here, but it errors out
# I am just using this for troubleshooting to ensure the mount points to the right spot
RUN ls -al /app/my_app && sleep 10

# Other additional setup steps relating to the `/app/my_app` directory occur here

# Start the web server
CMD ["httpd-foreground"]
```

When I run `docker compose up -d --build apache` I am getting this error - and can't seem to figure out why it's not mounting appropriately:

```
 => ERROR [12/25] RUN ls -al /app/my_app && sleep 10                                                                                         0.3s
------
 > [12/25] RUN ls -al /app/my_app && sleep 10:
#0 0.237 ls: cannot access '/app/my_app': No such file or directory
```

Any help or ideas would be very appreciated!

Comment: `RUN` commands in your dockerfile happens when you build the container. The mount only happens when you start the container. You say you get the error when running `docker compose up`, but I assume the error comes during the build step. At that time the volume is not mounted yet, hence the error.

Comment: How do I get the files mounted, and then run commands on them in the container in that case?

I'm trying to essentially run a few python related commands on the directories mounted.

Comment: agree with previous commenter. @Hanny, for that case you can run special docker exec command: `docker exec -it <containerHash> bash`. And in that terminal you can use any commands you want - `ls -al /app/my_app`. For build stage such sort of commands are usually used only for debugging purpose.

Comment: @Ryan I'm setting up a django app in this container, which I would like to automate the process of running `python manage.py collectstatic` in the apache container. I can only do that once the directories have been mounted - do I have to do that manually after the container is up? Or would inside the .Dockerfile be the right spot?

Comment: As far as i know there is only manual way. This mechanics works well - just ensure your paths are right, and mappings are right. No need for any extra work.

Comment: `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` directives as names imply are started when running container. These are right places to make initialization.

Comment: So if I wanted to run the collect static command after it was up - in the .Dockerfile I could do something like `CMD ["python", "manage.py", "collectstatic"]` and it would run after started?

Comment: Well, i got your point, python code should be explicitly copied into container, that's the right way of doing such sort of things. And volumes are not intended for that - they just provide initial configuration/persistance(db) data. See [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) or [ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) directives. Your build context should contain all essential assets for your application to work.

Comment: @Ryan that makes more sense. I see in further tutorials online there is always a line of `COPY . /app/my_app` in the .Dockerfile. I was trying to avoid that, as I had read copying things to the container was a 'bad practice', but in doing that it works as I would suspect. Thank you!

Comment: Copy is the only way of building docker images. There are some technics for optimization: .dockerignore, multistage builds. Just for reference.

Comment: @Hanny Maybe it was already clear from you discussion here, but volumes are not meant for things that should always be in the container. If you have a complete django setup you want in your container, you should copy everything needed into it. That's pretty much the whole point.